# My profile picture in the top bar is distorted

Tags: support, bug, top-bar, profile-picture

So this is what it looks like for me, there's a gray square which is not supposed to be there. This is persistent across computers and reboots and cache refreshes:

[image]

Comment: Reuploading should fix this.

Comment: For reference, here is the broken thumbnail: http://i.stack.imgur.com/b61AK.jpg?s=24&g=1